# Print from Peppermint 9 networked through tethered Android phone

Tags: networking, wifi, android, printer, smartphone

I have an 11 year old [ACER Aspire One zg5](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/327/~/where-can-i-find-information-on-the-model-zg5%3F) netbook running Peppermint 9 with a dead WiFi card, so I use an Android phone (Motorola One) to tether via USB to another PC; everything works with no issues (almost).

The problem is to install my printer ([Canon Pixma MG4250](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg4250.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=windows%2010%20(64-bit))) connected via WiFi, the drivers are installed (for printer and for scanner), scanner driver is scangearmp BUT when I run scangearmp command the program can not find any printer/scanner in the network, I refreshed few times update scanner list but no success the Canon Pixma is not visible.

My main laptop (OS Xubuntu 16.04.6 detects the printer/scanner without issues). Maybe some configuration on Android phone USB tethering and/or netbook missing ?

Netbook display this tether connection as WIRED, phone gets WiFi from router and printer is connected to the same network, phone mobile data is disabled so phone is connected only via WiFi.

Comment: Can you determine the IP address of the printer?   If so, look for a way to *specify* that, rather than just telling the system to scan for a printer.

Comment: yes, printer IP is 192.168.0.16, but how to set scangearmp to connect directly to this address? (I'll try to figure out)

Comment: OK, it's done, scanning with SANE scanimage or simple-scan